# How to end Else command in python

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome To Kai's Math Game!")
points = 0
ansr = input("What is 5+5?: ")
if ansr=="10":
    print("Correct")
    points += 1
    print("points:", points)
else:
    print("Wrong")
    quit()
    ansr = input("What is 25+25?: ")
    if ansr=="50":
        print("Correct")
        points += 3
```

I tried to replace `quit()` with `end()` but the same thing happens. I wanted it to go to the input statement on line 11 but instead it listens to the `else` command when the `if` condition should have been correct.

Comment: Why do you need `quit()` or `end()`?

Comment: Remove `quit()` and unindent everything after it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling quit() in the else block, which will immediately exit the program.

To fix this, remove the quit() call. You just need the print("Wrong") to indicate an incorrect answer, but still allow the program to continue:

```
print("Welcome To Kai's Math Game!")
points = 0
ansr = input("What is 5+5?: ")
if ansr=="10":
  print("Correct")
  points += 1
  print("points:", points)  
else:
  print("Wrong")

ansr = input("What is 25+25?: ")
if ansr=="50":
  print("Correct")
  points += 3
```

Now it will print "Wrong" if the first answer is incorrect, but continue on to ask the next question.

The quit() and exit() functions immediately terminate the program, so you don't want to call them if you want the code to keep running. Just use prints, variables, etc. to handle incorrect answers without exiting.

Comment: Thank You, but what if I did want to close the program if the user gets a question wrong?

Comment: @TheCoder86 Then you shouldn't put lines of code immediately afterward

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python. where should I put the lines. apologies for asking so many question's.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you program more manageable by making it "data driven".

Make a list of 3-tuples comprised of a question, an answer and the number of points to be gained by answering the question correctly.

In this example, if an answer is incorrect, we simply output "Wrong" and the program terminates. Only if all the questions are answered correctly do we show the accumulated score.

In order to add more questions and answers you merely have to edit the list of 3-tuples - i.e., the rest of the code doesn't change.

```
questions_and_answers = [
    ('5+5', '10', 1),
    ('25+25', '50', 3)
]

points = 0

print("Welcome To Kai's Math Game!")

for q, a, p in questions_and_answers:
    answer = input(f'What is {q}?: ')
    if answer == a:
        points += p
    else:
        print('Wrong')
        break
else:
    print(f'You answered all the questions correctly. You total point score is {points}')
```